# Error in Eval Try to define a model für lm

Tags: r

I try do define the model for my test and training dataset. But I get the following Error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'avg_rating' not found

But all of my datasets have the "avg_rating"

This is my code

```
lm_model <- train(avg_rating ~., data = trainingindex,method = "lm",na.action = na.omit, preProcess = c("scale", "center"),trControl = trainControl(method = "none"))
```

[image]

[image]

```
structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 58L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 
66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 74L, 77L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 83L, 84L, 
85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 113L, 115L, 
116L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 150L, 
152L, 154L, 155L, 157L, 158L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
168L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 
180L, 181L, 182L, 185L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 
207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 213L, 214L, 216L, 217L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 
223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 
235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 
247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 257L, 259L, 
260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 
274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 
287L, 288L, 290L, 291L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 
301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 
314L, 315L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 326L, 
327L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 
340L, 341L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 353L, 
354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 
366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 
377L, 378L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 386L, 387L,... 3687L), .Dim = c(2952L, 1
), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Resample1"))
```

```
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L), .Dim = c(30L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "Resample1"))
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(trainingindex)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Please do not share your data as an image.

Comment: so what would be a better way to share the data?, sorry for asking

Comment: Please copy the output of `dput(trainingindex)` of your console and paste it in your question above.

Comment: @Mrs_Ywi you didn't post the full ``dput()`` output. Please paste in the **whole** output into the question and format it using backticks. Thank you.

Comment: The data has 2952 observations, post a much smaller subset of it, say `dp(head(trainingindex,30))`.